# Is this why we require $(A-\lambda I)$ to be not invertible when finding eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

so suppose we have $(A-\lambda I)\underline{u}=0$.

I figure if $(A-\lambda I)$ was invertible then we would have $\underline{u}=(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$, so then $$(A-\lambda I)\underline{u}=(A-\lambda I)(A-\lambda I)^{-1}=I \neq 0.$$

So this is the reason we need a non-invertible matrix? I'm not sure if I can say 
$\underline{u}=(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ if $\underline{u}$ is a vector.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what an inverse is?

Comment: I think the confusion is because of my bad habits from manipulating algebra. I always forget when moving things from 1 side to the other is because you are performing the operation on both sides. I see my mistake now, I'm surprised I didn't see it, I'm just not used to matrix notation yet I guess.

Comment: It's a function you apply to the image of a function to get you back to the domain of the original function?

So with $\underline{u}=(A- \lambda I)$ I was calling a vector a function.

Comment: And for matrices, what does it mean for two matrices to be inverses?

Comment: $AA^{-1} = I$ So if I do $AB=C$, then $A^{-1}C=B$. I can't explain it any better, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Then do you understand why the line I quoted is nonsense?

Comment: I'm not completely sure I can explain it that well if I'm honest. I can see that if $(A-\lambda I)\underline{u}=0$, then $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}0=0$, not $\underline{u}$. So you can't get back to $\underline{u}$ if the equation is equal to zero, which means $(A-\lambda I)$ does not have an inverse.

 Thanks for the help btw I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A-\lambda I$ is invertible, then we can multiply its inverse on the left of both sides:

$$(A-\lambda I)^{-1} (A-\lambda I) \underline u = (A-\lambda I)^{-1} 0$$

Which becomes:

$$\underline u = 0$$

So the only solution is trivial.